# How detect "refresh" event with prototype?

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs, page-refresh

How detect "refresh" event with prototype? A Cross-browser solution?

Thanks,
Celso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to detect refreshes in particular, but you can catch the browser before the page gets unloaded (which happens when the user refreshes the page - as well as when they 'move' to another page)

In prototype this would look something like this:

```
Event.observe(window, 'beforeunload', yourFunction);
```

If you need to tell the difference, you could always bind some code to the links on your page that disables the above binding so that when the user actively clicks something you know it's a link (and not a refresh).

Comment: In this case, typing a new URL would also be counted as "refresh". But good starting point indeed.